# Intergrating IncrediBuild with Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, incredibuild

Me and my team are using GitHub Extension with our Visual Studio Team services.
Recently we have decided to improve development life-cycle speed using IncrediBuild.

Does anyone know how to integrate IncrediBuild with Visual Studio Team Services build server?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily integrate IncrediBuild with Visual Studio Team Services by adding a VSTS command line build step to execute an IncrediBuild buildconsole.exe or ibconsole.exe command.
For Team Services instructions on how to add a command line build step: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/command-line.
For further information on IncrediBuild's command line switches: http://www.incredibuild.com/webhelp/#BuildConsole.html.

During Q2 IncrediBuild is to release a dedicated extension for VSTS, for further information feel free to contact us at support@incredibuild.com

Disclaimer: the writer of this post works at IncrediBuild.